# Trouble with ZoomStates: 'ISciChartSurface' does not contain a definition for 'ZoomStates'

Tags: wpf, scichart

I've been looking through the new (and really great!) [SciChart Tutorial](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#Tutorial%2006%20-%20Adding%20Realtime%20Updates.html), and I've run into an issue.  I'm trying to use the ViewportManager API to make a realtime-updating chart zoomable and scrollable.  However this bit of code is not working:

```
// Don't Scroll if user is Zooming
if (ParentSurface.ZoomState == ZoomStates.UserZooming) {
    return currentVisibleRange;
}
```

I'm getting errors, for both ZoomState and ZoomStates, letting me know that ISciChartSurface does not contain a definition for ZoomState.  As far as I can tell ZoomStates should be an enum in SciChart.Charting.Visuals, however I can't find it in the Assembly Explorer.  Is it somehow missing from my installation of SciChart? Or have I - as per usual - made some really stupid mistake? What can I do about this?  Thanks!

Info:
SciChart version 4.1.1.8645

Full class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SciChart.Charting.ViewportManagers;
using SciChart.Charting.Visuals;
using SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes;
using SciChart.Data.Model;



namespace SciCharter {
    /// <summary>
    /// Applies a scrolling window to the chart unless the user is zooming or panning
    /// </summary>
    public class ScrollingViewportManager : DefaultViewportManager {
        private readonly double _windowSize;
        public ISciChartSurface ParentSurface { get; set; }

        public ScrollingViewportManager(double windowSize) {
            _windowSize = windowSize;
        }

        public override void AttachSciChartSurface(ISciChartSurface scs) {
            base.AttachSciChartSurface(scs);
            this.ParentSurface = scs;
        }

        protected override IRange OnCalculateNewXRange(IAxis xAxis) {
            // The Current XAxis Visible Range
            var currentVisibleRange = xAxis.VisibleRange.AsDoubleRange();

            // Don't Scroll if user is Zooming
            if (ParentSurface.ZoomState == ZoomStates.UserZooming) {
                return currentVisibleRange;
            }

            var maxXRange = xAxis.GetMaximumRange().AsDoubleRange();
            double xMax = Math.Max(maxXRange.Max, currentVisibleRange.Max);

            // Scroll showing latest window range
            return new DoubleRange(xMax - _windowSize, xMax);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article [SciChart WPF: New set of tutorials now online](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-wpf-new-set-tutorials-now-online/) it says:

> Tutorials Include
>   ...
>   [WPF Chart Tutorial 06 – Adding Realtime Updates](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/Tutorial%2006%20-%20Adding%20Realtime%20Updates.html) (15 minutes) uses some features from SciChart v4.2, which is in QA now and available on the nightly build feed only.

The SciChart WPF Nightly Builds are available from a private nuget feed. Full instructions on how to access them can be found [here](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17232/37/getting-nightly-builds-with-nuget).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That explains it! Thank you very much!